# Mongooose / MongoDB _id as String

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, mongoose, graphql-js

I faced a problem with fetching data from MongoDB. I got 
`ID cannot represent value: { _bsontype: "ObjectID", ... }`

Someone said:

> declare the _id of each model to the type of String

So it works, the problem is gone but is it okey to do this that way? I mean, MongoDB will not save IDs as objectIds for fun ^^. Or is it the same, to use String instead of ObjectIDs?

Comment: Not really sure where you are declaring this, but mongoose typically handles the conversion from string to ObjectId, so yeah, I think you're good :)

Comment: for example: const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  } } -- And thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: You don't need to declare your _id in the schema. That is handled by mongoose automatically. My guess is that the problem you had was in something else, but need more code to say something useful.

Comment: or you can transfer ObjectId to String by `_id.toString()`

Comment: in my resolver.js for graphql I have just written `getPost: async (_, args, { Post }) =>{ const post = await Post.find({}); return posts}` to get all Posts.

Comment: Try logging `post` before you send it back, because this part should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I found the solution how to work with the ID.
The ID should be an ObjectID as  mongoose creates it. So I work with GraphQL and I did not noticed, that GraphQL automatically parsed the _id(ObjectID) to id(String).

Example:

In the typeDefs.gql do not write _id: ID!, instead write id: ID!

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

Then we get out id as a simple string and the problem is gone.